# How can i get a return value from the DialogFragment for Datepicker in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker, sharedpreferences, return-value, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to write a code in Android to get saved date from the date picker and wants to show in the Toast.  I have a Grid of **10x10** and clicking on each cell a Datepicker appears. I am selecting some dates and pressing Done then the selected date saved in a Sharedpreference object. I am getting correct saved result in the **Log Cat** also but I am not able to get correct value in the Toast.

**My Code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.complexdatepicker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{

ArrayList<String> abc;

TestGrid tg;

GridView gv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        abc = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {

            abc.add(String.valueOf(i));

        }


        tg = new TestGrid(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,abc);

        gv.setAdapter(tg);


}
}
```

**TestGrid.java**

```
package com.example.complexdatepicker;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class TestGrid extends BaseAdapter
{

    private ArrayList<String> abc;

    private FragmentActivity activity;

    private Context context; 

    String text;

    int c = 0;

    int x = 0;

    DialogFragment newFragment;



    public TestGrid(FragmentActivity activity , Context cont,ArrayList<String> abc)
    {

        super();

        this.activity=activity;

        this.context = cont;

        this.abc = abc;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {

        return abc.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int in) 
    {       

        return abc.get(in);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {

        return 0;

    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView txt;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
    {

        final SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);

        ViewHolder view;

        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(arg1==null)
        {

            view = new ViewHolder();

            arg1 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test_grid, null);

            view.txt = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);

            arg1.setTag(view);

        }
        else
        {

            view = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();

        }



         View.OnClickListener alert = new OnClickListener() 
         {


                public void onClick(View v) 
                {


                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), abc.get(arg0)+" - Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();

                    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    // Getting Error here //

          // The method setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()   {}) is undefined for the type DialogFragment                
                    newFragment.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd)
                        {

                            String saved_date = pref.getString("SavedDate", null);

                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "SavedDate : "+saved_date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


                        }




                    });



                    newFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");       

                }


         };



        view.txt.setOnClickListener(alert);



        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
        {



            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            {

                String saved_date = pref.getString("SavedDate", null);

                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "SavedDate : "+saved_date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }        


        };


        text = String.valueOf(abc.get(arg0));

        view.txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.txtbk);

        view.txt.setTextSize(18);

        view.txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        view.txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);    

        view.txt.setText(text);

        return arg1;

    }




    @SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "NewApi" })
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
    {


        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener externalListener;

        public void setOnDateSetListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener)
        {
            this.externalListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {


                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

                int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);


        }


        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd)
        {

            SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);

            Editor et = pref.edit();

            et.putString("SavedDate", String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy));

            et.commit();

            Log.d("SavedDate : ", String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy));

            if(externalListener != null)


                externalListener.onDateSet(view, yy, mm, dd);




        }


        public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) 
        {



        }


    }


}
```

The problem i am facing from my code is , whenever i am clicking on a cell, the Date-picker appears and also the Sharedpreference object starts displaying in the Toast. But it shows the older value.

After choosing the Dates from date-picker the value got saved in the Sharedpreference object but not finding any technique to show the latest saved result in the Toast.

Please help me out , suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that unlike a lot of other environments, showing a modal dialog in Android does not block the execution of the caller. So, you need to add a listener to your dialog fragment so that the event can bubble to the caller.

```
class SelectDateFragment  extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener externalListener;

public void setOnDateSetListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener{
    this.externalListener = listener;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd){

   SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);

   Editor et = pref.edit();
   et.putString("SavedDate", String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy));
   et.commit();

   Log.d("SavedDate : ", String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy));

   if(externalListener != null)
       externalListener.OnDateSet(view, yy, mm, dd);

    }
}
```

Change the declaration of the newFragment member so that we can call our custom functions:

```
SelectDateFragment newFragment;
```

Finally,add a listener in the class that calls the DatePicker into existence:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{

     newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     newFragment.setArguments(args);


     newFragment.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
         public void onDateSet(View view, int yy, int mm, int dd){
             String saved_date = pref.getString("SavedDate", null);
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "SavedDate : "+saved_date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

         }
     });

    newFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");   

   }
```

Its cumbersome I know, but it seems that we have to dance to Google's tune on this one.

Comment: getting following error , The method setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){}) is undefined for the type DialogFragment  , please help me out...

Comment: Have you defined the method in `SelectDateFragment` yet?

Comment: Yes i have done all , as you have suggested to me  , i am editing my question ... please go through it...

Comment: Ah, I see it. You need to declare newFragment as a `SelectDateFragment` to be able to call methods on the sub class. Please see my edit.

Comment: I would say ... you completely brilliant ... you saved my day... buddy ... thanks a lot ... everything works... awesome... thank you so much....

Comment: No problem here to help. Upvoting and accepting answers earns you rep, which gains you more privileges on SO :)

Comment: I can do accepting your answer sorry i don't have much reputation to do Upvote :( ...

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code. 
`Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy), 3000).show();`

Comment: No No , i am already displaying in the Log cat , please understand my question properly .... how can i display latest saved result in the getview function .... from saved Sharedprefrence object....

Comment: when will your perform latest action?

Comment: My friend you still not understanding my question , how can i get a return value after closing the datepicker dialog box , so that .. i can apply some if condition , if the condition satisfies then the save_date String variable will display in the Toast or AlertBox or in TextView....

Comment: `private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {//show toast
           }
        };
}`

Comment: @Ramki Anba If you check his question, then he already knows this but does not know how to get the selected date into the calling fragment. I suspect that ultimately he does not want to show the date in a toast, but perform so other, more useful operation. Please read questions carefully before answering

Comment: sorry guys. `SharedPreferences pref` should be in public access if it is in same class `pref.edit().putString("SavedDate", "your data").commit();` this is for write into SharedPreferences

Comment: @Ramki Anba , listen brother ... i think you are in a hurry for something ... you are not reading my question properly. I am getting correct result in the Log Cat and also saving in the SharedPreference object but can't able to show the latest result from SharedPreference object in the getview function ...

Comment: @user3668350 export your SharedPreferences and check it your value is there or not?

Comment: Yes it's there ... whenever i clicking again any of the cell then i am getting saved result in the Toast ... actual problem is Cell click call the DialogFragment and also Sharedpreference object display at a time .. what i want is ... displaying in the toast should happen after closing the dialog box...

Comment: You used `SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);` so you've SharedPreferences in name of TestData. When you want to get the value from SharedPreferences you should use with same name that `SharedPreferences pref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TestDate", 0);`

Comment: You are just wasting my time .... just check to CurlyPaul , how he has brilliantly done ... and understood my question properly.... and solved my issue....

Comment: this may helps you `public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // show toast
        }`

Comment: I would say ... please go to your tv set and have coke ... and come ... please have a brief look my question and CurlyPaul's  answer... then you can think about it...